# User uploading an advert to car site in PHP

Tags: php, forms, phpmyadmin, image-uploading

I'm being driven crazy trying to work out how I can allow a user to upload an advert to a car site I am creating for a Uni project.
The user should be able to enter the car details and an image of the car. After doing a lot of searching around I saw it's advised an image is uploaded to a directory and the path stored in a database. I wanted to assign new names to the image so it is unique.
The code that uploads the image to the directory works fine and renames. My problem is inserting the data into the database. I am getting the error "Notice: Array to string conversion" I'm guessing this is from the array where the renaming is done? Please help. Here is my PHP code (i know it's a little all over the place cutting etc and needs tidying up).

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST['upload_car'])){

$car_make = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['make']);

$car_model = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['model']);

$car_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);

$car_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['year']);

$car_mileage = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mileage']);

$car_engine = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['engine']);

$car_gearbox = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gearbox']);

$car_area = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['area']);

$car_colour = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['colour']);

$car_descr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']); 

$usr_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['mem_ID']);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$usr_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $contact_num = $row['phone'];
        $contact_email = $row['email'];
    }
}

$image = $_FILES['image'];
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_TmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_error = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$imageExt = explode('.', $image_name);
$imageActualExt = strtolower(end($imageExt));
$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

if(in_array($imageActualExt, $allowed)){
    if($image_error === 0){
        if($image_size < 1000000){
            $image_nameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$imageActualExt;
            $imageDestination = 'uploads/'.$image_nameNew;
            move_uploaded_file($image_TmpName, $imageDestination);
        }else{
            echo"Your image is too big";
        }
    }else{
        echo"There was a problem uploading";
    }
}else{
    echo "You can not upload that file type.";
}




if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $car_make, $car_model)){
    $error = true;
    echo'<script>alert("Name must contain only alphabets and space.")</script>';
}



if(!$error){
    if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO car(make, model, price, year, milage, engine_size, gearbox, area, colour,
                            vehicle_descr, photo, phot_dest, contact_num, contact_email, id)
    VALUES('" . $car_make ."', '" . $car_model . "', '" . $car_price . "', '" . $car_year . "', '" . $car_mileage . "',
    '" . $car_engine . "', '" . $car_gearbox . "', '" . $car_area . "', '" . $car_colour . "', '" . $car_descr . "',
    '" . $image_nameNew . "', '" . $imageDestination . "', '" . $contact_num . "', '" . $contact_email . "', '" . $usr_id . "' )"))
    {

        echo'<script>alert("Your car has been uploaded")</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo'<script>alert("Error uploading! Please try again later")</script>';
    }
}
 }

   ?>
```

Comment: the error should tell you the line number

Comment: Yes it's on line 81 which is my VALUES being inserted

Comment: are you sure none of the fields which are obtained from `POST` is an array ? Can you post a `print_r($_POST)` here ?

Comment: Array ( [make] => Honda [model] => Civic [price] => 17000 [year] => 2017 [mileage] => 10000 [engine] => 1.7 [gearbox] => Manual [area] => BS1 ST17 [colour] => Grey [description] => 5 seats. 5 doors. air con. like new [upload_car] => ) 
Thats what print_r returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or specifically this line:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $car_make, $car_model)){
```

The documentation of the third parameter explicitly states that:

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So `$car_model` is turned into an array before your `INSERT` string is built.

---

I haven't reviewed your code but changing it to:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $car_make)){
```

would probably solve your issue.

Comment: That has fixed the error of the array problem thank you! but the upload is still not working? And there isn't any clue as to why now? It's doing the last echo "Error uploading! Please try again later"

Comment: @JamesVickers You need to detect MySQL errors. Look at the [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) examples.

Comment: Thank you! This was the error and I also typo in my insert query